# How to properly format Python Print with multiple parameters?

Tags: python, printing

Currently I am getting the following output:

```
data1     57578896
data2     57695876
anotherdata     59859485
```

What formatting do I add, so that it will look something like this:

```
data1          57578896
data2          57695876
anotherdata    59859485
```

What I have now looks like this:

```
print "%s     %d" % (input_list[i], data)
```

Comment: Try putting tabs between the two. If not then you gotta get length of the string and subtract that from desired spaces and print that many spaces.

Comment: You can specify how wide you want a particular field to be: for example, %30s says to print your string in a field padded to at least 30 characters.

Comment: Did you try a field with specifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a width specifier like:

```
print "%-14s%d" % (input_list[i], data)
```